# Windows types won't let my callback access local variables, any workaround?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, lambda, scoping

I'm trying to use the [`EnumWindows`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumwindows) function, which takes a [`WNDENUMPROC`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633498(v=VS.85).aspx) as callback with a lambda in order to access local variables. Unfrotunately if i try to use `[&]` the compiler will tell me types don't match.
What i'm trying:

```
HWND get_wallpaper_window()
    {
    HWND progman = FindWindow(L"ProgMan", NULL);
    SendMessageTimeout(progman, 0x052C, 0, 0, SMTO_NORMAL, 1000, nullptr);

    HWND wallpaper_hwnd;
    EnumWindows(
            // Error here 
            [&](HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam) -> BOOL CALLBACK 
                    {
                    HWND p = FindWindowEx(hwnd, NULL, L"SHELLDLL_DefView", NULL);
                    if (p) { wallpaper_hwnd = FindWindowEx(NULL, hwnd, L"WorkerW", NULL); }
                    }
            , NULL);
    return wallpaper_hwnd;
    }
```

The only solution i could come up with is making wallpaper_hwnd global and defining the lambda with `[]`, but since it's only needed when returned from that function and not needed globally i'd rather avoid that.

I love using globals way more than people would advice, but i only do when the global variable is something that interacts with the whole program, and this is not the case.

Any better solution i'm missing?

Comment: What is the actual problem this code tries to solve? To depend on the internal window structure of the desktop like this, may very well brake in future Windows versions.

Comment: @zett42 customization. It's very easy to make an overly by just drawing on the generic "display" but if you need to draw on the very back that's the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lambda functions that capture outside variables cannot be used as Win32 callbacks. They are not convertible to raw function pointers.

The solution in your case is to pass a pointer to something as the LPARAM parameter of EnumWindows(), which is passed to the callback.

```
class A {...};
A a;
EnumWindows([](HWND   hwnd,LPARAM lParam) -> BOOL {
A* a = (A*)lParam;
...
},(LPARAM)&a);
```

Most windows functions that require a callback support passing a user-defined value which can be a pointer to a structure. The compiler is smart enough to convert a non-capturing lambda to CALLBACK (=_stdcall) calling convention automatically.

Comment: to avoid c-style conversion, (LPARAM)&a should be a static_cast or a reinterpret_cast?

Comment: There is no reason to avoid C-style conversion when using C style functions like Win32 ones. Besides, reinterpret_cast  does exactly what the C cast is doing with more typing.

Comment: C-style casts select the cast that best matches (`static_cast`, `const_cast` or `reinterpret_cast` – or a combination of). While it *can* be used, I personally would rather recommend using `reinterpret_cast` anyway. It just expresses more clearly what one actually is doing – in spite of having to write a bit more.

Comment: @Aconcagua this type of casting is too common in Win32 functions. It's common for the writer to know what is actually doing. Although that casting should be avoided, in Win32 programming it is necessary many times and it's not likely that one will misunderstand the meaning.

Comment: *In* Win32 functions? Well, these *are* C functions. If you mean "when using Win32 functions in C++", then I'd consider it widely established *bad practice*. I am stricter here: Use C++ casts in C++, C (-style) casts in C and in headers that need to be compatible to both.

Comment: Admitted, here might two *oppinions* clash, so it might not be worth to argue further – just let's have both presented and each reader decide on its own...

Comment: @Aconcagua actually, when using Win32 it's C++. No serious developer uses plain C unless there is some very weird restriction, in Windows there isn't. However much of the functions are C like, full of casting like that. So the user is very much expected to be confident. If the user needs to use reinterpret_cast to be sure of what he is doing, they should not mess with Win32 anyway.

Comment: it's not like there's many alternatives to Win32 to interact deeply with Windows. Someday hopefully at microsoft they will come out with a modern c++ alternative.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis Have a look at any arbitrary windows header – all of them have the famous `#ifdef __cplusplus extern "C"` section around. They are C-*compatible* functions at least, in which language they *actually* have been written (and that's not restricted only to C or C++...) we won't ever be able to tell anyway...

Comment: @Barnack If they made a C++ API what about people using languages that weren't C++?

Comment: @bar: They [already have](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/). Now here's the deal: It's so darn complex and hard to use, that hardly anyone does. Try it, for a day, and spend the better part of it deciphering your compiler's error diagnostics.

Comment: This is not quite true. It's usable and, for version 1903+, available for win32 apps. Also, it's not a win32 replacement. Check my library https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1279856/UwpAX-A-small-library-for-including-Xaml-controls.

Comment: The Windows Runtime has been available for classic desktop applications since Windows 8 (with the exception of those types, that require app identity). Of course C++/WinRT is *"usable"*, but using it requires that you are a C++ veteran. And even then, the error diagnostics generated by the compiler are daunting, debugging code a challenge, and navigating the code is a nightmare. The Windows Runtime *is* the designated successor to the Windows API, too. New features will appear in the Windows Runtime, not the Windows API (like the multi-element clipboard).

Comment: Still not quite true, new features do appear in API only (for example, see [Antimalware Scan Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/el-gr/windows/desktop/AMSI/antimalware-scan-interface-functions)). Also, generally Windows programming requires C++ expertise (unless one thinks that command line can achieve everything).

Comment: The point is, that the Windows API is exposed **strictly** as a C interface. To use it, no expertise other than calling a C API is required. And using the Windows API from C++ doesn't make it any more accessible (maybe with the exception of COM and GDI+). Still, that's an option you have. With C++/WinRT you don't have that option, and you will need to understand templates, ADL, overload resolution, coroutines, etc. You do not get to choose, whether you want to know C++ inside and out, you absolutely must, if you decide to use the C++/WinRT language projection.

Comment: More on topic, though, that lambda should probably be `noexcept`. You wouldn't want your C++ exceptions to travel across stack frames, that aren't [in on the joke](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120910-00/?p=6653).

Answer (score 2):

> Any better solution i'm missing?

Well, yes, that NULL in the second parameter is passed back to the callback so you can easily use it to propagate local state.

```
HWND get_wallpaper_window()
    {
    HWND progman = FindWindow(L"ProgMan", NULL);
    SendMessageTimeout(progman, 0x052C, 0, 0, SMTO_NORMAL, 1000, nullptr);

    HWND wallpaper_hwnd;
    EnumWindows(
            [](HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam) -> BOOL CALLBACK 
                {
                    auto wallpaper_hwnd_ptr = reinterpret_cast<HWND*>(lParam);
                    HWND p = FindWindowEx(hwnd, NULL, L"SHELLDLL_DefView", NULL);
                    if (p) { *wallpaper_hwnd = FindWindowEx(NULL, hwnd, L"WorkerW", NULL); }
                    }
            , &wallpaper_hwnd);
    return wallpaper_hwnd;
    }
```

Comment: already tried, but it gives me a type error… should i reinterpret cast it?

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis Maybe I'm misunderstanding the nature of HWND, but OP wants his local variable to have been updated once `EnumWindows` has finished, so it has to be a pointer to a `HWND`, no?

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis, yes, and that pointer is what needs to be assigned within the callback, not the object it's pointing at.

Comment: The error that he gets then is the passing of &wallpaper_hwnd, it needs probably (LPARAM)&wallpaper_hwnd.

Comment: that's it, the other answer got it correct @MichaelChourdakis

Comment: `wallpaper_hwnd` should be initialized (`wallpaper_hwnd = nullptr;`). Just in case.